# cassandra-cli: unable to coerce 'allias' to version 1 UUID

Tags: exception, cassandra, uuid, coerce

I'm triyng to create a column family with TimeUUIDType as name of row:

```
create column family users
with column_type = 'Standard'
and comparator = 'TimeUUIDType'
and default_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and key_validation_class = 'UTF8Type'
and memtable_operations = 0.290625
and memtable_throughput = 62
and memtable_flush_after = 1440
and rows_cached = 0.0
and row_cache_save_period = 0
and keys_cached = 200000.0
and key_cache_save_period = 14400
and read_repair_chance = 1.0
and gc_grace = 864000
and min_compaction_threshold = 4
and max_compaction_threshold = 32
and replicate_on_write = true
and row_cache_provider = 'ConcurrentLinkedHashCacheProvider'
and column_metadata=[
{column_name: allias, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS, index_name: allias},
{column_name: st_user_id, validation_class: TimeUUIDType, index_type: KEYS, index_name: st_user_id},
{column_name: st_money, validation_class: IntegerType},
{column_name: mail, validation_class: UTF8Type},
{column_name: password, validation_class: UTF8Type},
{column_name: last_visit, validation_class: DateType},
{column_name: registered, validation_class: DateType}
];
```

But im getting an exception:

> org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.MarshalException: unable to coerce
>   'allias' to v ersion 1 UUID

What i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The comparator property of a column family is used for ordering the columns within a row. You are attempting to use a TimeUUID comparator, which would require that each column name be a TimeUUID value.

If you want to use TimeUUIDs as your row keys, but strings for column names you likely just want to switch the values for those settings,

```
comparator = 'UTF8Type',
key_validation_class = 'TimeUUIDType'
```